# SAS Syntax Highlighting in Sublime

Tags: sas, syntax-highlighting, sublimetext3

I would like to be able to use Sublime 3 as my SAS text editor but cannot seem to configure Sublime to do so. I've visited http://implementing-vdw.blogspot.com/2012/10/new-sublime-text-package-available-for.html and haven't been able to actually get the SAS syntax highlighting to work in 
Sublime.

Here's what I did, I don't have/know github so I downloaded the zip file as instructed and placed its contents in C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\Packages\SAS. I closed sublime and reopened but don't see SAS as an available syntax.

I'm sure I need to perform another step or two but I don't know what.

Comment: As noted in the GitHub ReadMe, Roy is working on Sublime Text 3 Beta version, it works in Sublime Text 2.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the steps you followed to get the SAS package working in Sublime. It works fine for me...

Comment: Here's how I got this to work:
1. download the zip file from the above blogspot location (I also tried using git but got a publickey access error)
2. use Sublime -> Preferences -> Browse Packages to find the directory where this needs to be unzipped
3. unzipped the zip file into the appropriate directory (on MacOS, it was ~/Library/Application\ Support/Sublime\ Text\ 3/Packages/)
4. renamed the unzipped folder to SAS
5. at this point, I am able to select the SAS syntax in Sublime via View -> Syntax -> SAS

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Determined what the issue was, the 'Packages' directory where I installed Sublime Text 3 isn't the exact directory where you need to place the SAS folder. As a doublecheck to ensure you are placing the SAS folder in the correct location open Sublime -> Preferences -> Browse Packages..., this is the location where the SAS folder should be placed. Once done you will see SAS syntax available under View -> Syntax.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I got this to work:

1. download the zip file from the above blogspot location (I also tried
   using git but got a publickey access error)
2. use Sublime -> Preferences -> Browse Packages to find the directory where this needs to be unzipped
3. unzip the zip file into the appropriate directory (on MacOS, it was ~/Library/Application\ Support/Sublime\ Text\ 3/Packages/)
4. rename the unzipped folder to SAS
5. at this point, I can select the SAS syntax in Sublime via View -> Syntax -> SAS